# When are history records created

Tags: history-tracking, field-history, transaction

Two types of transactions work on a set of records. First type selects records that don't have a flag set and sets it. The second transaction selects those records that have a flag set and removes the flag.

It would appear that those transaction types are mutually exclusive. However, field history reports that a record had the flag set and then removed at exactly the same timestamp.

My question is when exactly are history records created? Are they created when a transaction finally commits or with each DML call of the transaction?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the 'second transaction'?  Truly two different SFDC transactions or just triggers firing a second time, say after a RSF, workflow field update, or process builder update?

Comment: @cropredy Two different transactions initiated by two http requests.

Comment: Then the history records should have different timestamps - since the UI time resolution is not down to the ms; did you do SOQL on the actual history records to see their CreatedDate field value?

Comment: I did, and the timestamps are exactly the same.

Comment: weird - are you sure the first transaction doesn't (via a workflow or PB) reset the flag?